# jQuery/Javascript: Pull out box from behind box

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I have 4 boxes placed next to each other and I want to make so that when a user clicks on one of the boxes, a new box slides out next to it, pushing the other ones to the right.

So if the second box is clicked, a new boxes slides out to the right, pushing box 3 & 4 to the right.

This is how my boxes is setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/g8YXK/1/

I kind of don't know where I should start with writing Javascript or jQuery code.

Should mention that I want it to "slide back" when same box is pressed again

Comment: "I kind of don't know where I should start with writing Javascript or jQuery code." Well then this is definitely not the place to start... 30 days to jQuery (https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/) You got a lot to learn my man.

Comment: Yeah I know. I was actually thinking of really learning jQuery so thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/r85WK/

It might require a tweak here or there, depending on how you want everything to work, but the bulk of what you're asking for is built in there.

Comment: That's amazing! Though how can I make it so that when you press the same box again the box "slides back"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#boxes li a").click(function(){
    var box = $(this).parent().clone();
    $(this).append(box);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hofo/btp8K/2/